# Legends get cut off with pie chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid chart library to show pie chart in my app
The legends / chart description labels are not wrapping below one another
I used `pieChart.legend.isWordWrapEnabled=true` but it doesn't work out

This is my xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".equity.EquityFragment">

<include
    android:id="@+id/pageTitleLayout"
    layout="@layout/page_title" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pageTitleLayout" />
<include
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    layout="@layout/view_progress_loader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is code

```
private fun createChart(chartData:List<EquityPieChart>){
    val pieEntry= chartData.map { PieEntry(it.equity,it.name) }
    val rnd = Random()
    val colors = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in chartData.indices){
        colors.add(Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)))
    }
    val dataSet=PieDataSet(pieEntry,getString(R.string.equity_title))
    dataSet.colors=colors
    binding.pieChart.data = PieData(dataSet)
    binding.pieChart.isDrawHoleEnabled=false
    binding.pieChart.legend.isWordWrapEnabled=true
    binding.pieChart.invalidate()

}
```

this is the UI i get in device

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing like this with the help of flexboxlayout

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".equity.EquityFragment">

<include
    android:id="@+id/pageTitleLayout"
    layout="@layout/page_title" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chartLabels"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pageTitleLayout" />

<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/chartLabels"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    layout="@layout/view_progress_loader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Legend layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:padding="2dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/legendBox"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/legendTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/legendTitle"/>

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/legendTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="xxxxjdsfjsdfj"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/legendBox"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kotlin code

```
 private fun createChart(chartData: List<EquityPieChart>) {
    val pieEntry = chartData.map { PieEntry(it.equity) }
    val rnd = Random()
    val colors = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in chartData.indices) {
        colors.add(Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)))
    }
    val dataSet = PieDataSet(pieEntry, getString(R.string.equity_title))
    dataSet.colors = colors
    dataSet.valueTextSize = 14f
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false)
    dataSet.valueTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.white)
    binding.pieChart.data = PieData(dataSet)
    binding.pieChart.isDrawHoleEnabled = false
    binding.pieChart.description = Description().apply { text="" }
    binding.pieChart.invalidate()
    binding.pieChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);
    binding.pieChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    creatChartLabels(colors,chartData)
}

private fun creatChartLabels(colors:List<Int>,chartData: List<EquityPieChart>){
    for (i in chartData.indices) {
        val view=ItemLegendBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        view.legendBox.setBackgroundColor(colors[i])
        view.legendTitle.text=chartData[i].name
        binding.chartLabels.addView(view.root)
    }
}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The text of legends are too big to be fit inside the graph. One way is to keep them outside the graph.
The following attribute can be added to achieve this job:
`setDrawInside()`

Please use this code:

```
Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
l.setDrawInside(false);
l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
l.setYEntrySpace(0f);
l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

This will set the `legend` outside the graph.

Comment: doesn't work. tried this

Answer (score -1):

I was using the same library and faced the same issue. To fix this issue, please follow below steps:

1. Set properties for legends such as legend.setWordWrapEnabled(true) and legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT).
2. Most important thing is, put 'setData' method of piechart at the end after setting all the properties of piechart.